# Is it possible to reverse a linked list that contains a cycle?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I'm looking at some interview questions, and one of them asks to reverse a linked list that contains a cycle. So suppose I had a linked list like the following:

```
          F <- E
          |    /\
          V    |
A -> B -> C -> D
```

Then reversing the list would create the following:

```
          F -> E
         /\    |
          |    V
A <- B <- C <- D
```

The problem here is that there's a conflict between which nodes C should be pointing at. So would we just eliminate the link between C and F?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mathematically, you can think of a linked list (possibly containing a cycle) as a partial function from a set of nodes into itself, where each node maps to its successor and every node is eventually reachable from the start node.  (The last node has no successor).  Reversing a linked list would then entail inverting this function, since following a link and then going backwards across it should end you up back where you started.

If the linked list does not contain a cycle, then this partial function is injective (one-to-one), meaning that no two nodes map to the same successor.  Injective functions can indeed be inverted, which is why you can reverse a regular linked list.  However, if the list contains a cycle (and isn’t just one large cycle), then there are two nodes with the same successor, so the function is not injective and thus does not have an inverse.  So no, you cannot reverse the linked list and expect to get another linked list, if the list has a cycle.

However, if you treat the linked list as a more general graph in which each node can have any number of incoming or outgoing edges, then the inverse does exist.  It's just not a linked list anymore.

Comment: Excellent breakdown and clear explanation. Thank you very much.

Comment: @templatetypedef - "if you treat the linked list as a more general graph in which each node can have any number of incoming or outgoing edges, then the inverse does exist". Can you extrapolate on this a little please? The graph would still have cycles, meaning that the same problem you pointed out would still exist, namely that "there are two nodes with the same successor" in the graph. How would that situation be addressed?

Comment: @TravisJ- If you have a linked list that contains a cycle and you reverse all the edges, then some cells might have multiple outgoing edges.  That's a problem if you want the result to be a linked list, but it's totally fine if you allow for multiple outgoing edges from each node.  Does that make sense?

Comment: But the specific cycle where the 'last' node points to the 'first' node does not have this problem and can be reversed while still being a linked list. (eg. if F pointed at A in the example in the question)

Comment: @MattCochrane Great point, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The original list would be `AB CDEF CDEF CDEF ...`  To reverse that you'd need a linked list that generates `FEDC` an infinite number of times followed by `BA`, so I'd say no, there's no way to build a linked list that would generate that sequence.

Comment: But, given the consumer of the list can never reach the final BA, for some purposes a loop on FEDC may serve as a reversal....